# Hide 'this' and another element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

Consider my element structure

```
<a href="#" class="close">X</a>
<div class="container">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Now on click of the anchor tag I need to hide both the elements,

```
$('body').on('click', '.close', function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('.container').hide();
});
```

How do I chain both the `hide()` statements into one?

Comment: Any particular reason why you need this?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - Basically for learning and to reduce the number of lines of code.

Comment: @GibinEalias There you go. One liner is possible :) Group them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot as the selectors are different. You can only chain if you are operating on same select element.

However, if you want to minimise the line you can consider grouping them instead of chaining using [add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/).

```
$(this).add('.container').hide();
```

or

```
$('.container').add(this).hide();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `add()` to combine multiple selectors in to a single jQuery object:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
  $(this).add('.container').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="close">X</a>
<div class="container">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
$('body').on('click', '.close', function(){
    $(".close, .container").hide();
});
```

Comment: This hides all the close buttons on the page.